# How to flash C code to STM32 board with CLion?

Tags: build, embedded, microcontroller, stm32, clion

I use Eclipse to develop for my STM32F746G-DISCOVERY board, but I would like to switch to CLion. I followed this tutorial (https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2019/02/clion-2019-1-eap-clion-for-embedded-development-part-iii/) for that. Everything looking good so far, so I would like to flash the pre-generated "helloworld" code to the board. I suppose it should be done via UPLOAD. When I click build I have the following error message. When I hit RUN the process finished with exit code 127.

```
====================[ Build | UPLOAD | Debug ]==================================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/hordon/Desktop/GreenFox/CLionSTM32/cmake-build-debug --target UPLOAD -- -j 2
[100%] Built target ClionSTM32.elf
GNU gdb (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 8-2018-q4-major) 8.2.50.20181213-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=arm-none-eabi".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
tcp:127.0.0.1:3333: Operation timed out.
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
You can't do that when your target is `None'
[100%] Built target UPLOAD

Build finished

====================[ Build | ClionSTM32.elf | Debug ]==========================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/hordon/Desktop/GreenFox/CLionSTM32/cmake-build-debug --target ClionSTM32.elf -- -j 2
[100%] Built target ClionSTM32.elf

Build finished
```

I'm just getting started with microcontrollers, but my best guess is that CLion can't reach the board (which is connected for sure). I have no clue how to fix this.

Comment: The Discovery board integrates an STlink JTAG/SWD debug/programming interface.  Presumably you will need to configure your IDE to support that.  It is not clear that you have done so.  For just programming you can use the stand-alone STLink programming tool.

Comment: _"You can't do that when your target is `None""_ : A target other than none might be a good idea.

Comment: building a binary and loading into the board are two separate things, some IDEs will bridge the gap but no reason you have to.  If you can build a binary there are a few ways at least to get that binary into the board.

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate the STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe from [STM32CubeProgrammer](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html) into the process. Something like `<full path> STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe -P <File_Path> [<Address>] [ske] [skpv]` needs to be called when you want to upload the binary.